# Get last link from a div in jquery or backbone

Tags: jquery, html, templates, backbone.js, view

I have the following template

```
   <div id="aboutCompletedTasksContainer">
        <div id="completedTasksContainer">
            <a href="#{langPath}/#projects-#{projectID}/tasks/completed">
                <h:outputFormat value="#{msgProPro.Panel_Tasks_Completed_Detail}" escape="false">
                    <f:param value="#{numberOfCompletedTasks}"/>
                    <f:param value="#{numberOfTasksListsWithCompletedTasks}"/>
                </h:outputFormat>
            </a>
        </div>
```

as you can see, after every link there is a comma displayed. I need to take are ference to the last link displayed and delete the comma. How can I manage that in jquery or backbone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use last child selector in JQuery : $("div a:last-child")

Please see [JQuery documentation about last child selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)